# SQL query group by with null values is returning duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have following query

My @dates table has following records:

```
month    year  saledate
9         2020  2020-09-01
10        2020  2020-10-01
11        2020  2020-11-01

with monthlysalesdata as(
select month(salesdate) as salemonth, year(salesdate) as saleyear,salesrepid, salespercentage
from salesrecords r
join @dates d on d.saledate = r.salesdate
group by salesrepid, salesdate),
averagefor3months as(
select 0 as salemonth, 0 as saleyear, salesrepid, salespercentage
from monthlysalesdata
group by salesrepid)
finallist as(
select * from monthlysalesdata
union
select * from averagefor3months
```

This query returns following records which gives duplicate for a averagefor3months result set when there is null record in the first monthlyresultdata. how to achieve average for 3 months as one record instead of having duplicates?

```
salesrepid  salemonth saleyear   percentage
    232           0       0          null    -------------this is the duplicate record
    232           0       0          90
    232           9       2020       80
    232           10      2020       null
    232           11      2020       100

My first cte has this result:

salerepid      month    year     percentage 
---------------------------------------------  
   232           9       2020       80
   232           10      2020       null
   232           11      2020       100
My second cte has this result:

 salerepid      month   year     percentage 
    ---------------------------------------------  
       232           0       0      null
       232          0      0         90
How to avoid the duplicate record in my second cte,
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to accomplish.  And what results *do* you want?  Your query is not syntactically correct either.

Comment: You are right the first cte i eliminated how i am getting the null values for simplicity sake, assuming my first cte has three records with month 9 and month 11 having values and month 10 is null, with my second cte i am trying to achieve a average of month 9, 10 , 11 and final union should have four records, 0 for all three months, month 9, month 10, month 11. but my union is giving me 5 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want a summary row per sales rep based on some aggregation.  Your question is not clear on what is needed for the aggregation, but something like this:

```
with ym as (
      select r.salesrepid, d.year, d.month, sum(<something>) as whatever
      from salesrecords r join
           @dates d 
           on d.saledate = r.salesdate
      group by r.salesrepid, d.year, d.month
     )
select ym.*
from ym
union all
select salesrepid, null, null, avg(whatever)
from hm
group by salesrepid;
```

Comment: yes you are right, but this second aggregate is giving duplicate records if one of the records in the first cte has null values for the aggregate, does this make sense ?

Comment: salerepid      month year  percentage 
  252  0 0 NULL 
  252  0 0 83.33

Answer (score 0):

I updated to selected the group by from the table directly instead of the previous cte and got my results. Thank you all for helping

```
with ym as (
      select r.salesrepid, d.year, d.month, sum(<something>) as whatever
      from salesrecords r join
           @dates d 
           on d.saledate = r.salesdate
      group by r.salesrepid, d.year, d.month
     ),
 threemonthsaverage as(
select r.salesrepid, r.year, r.month, sum(something) as whatever
from salesrecords as r
group by salesrepid)
select ym *
union
select threemonthsaverage*
```